# Pyodbc Transactions not Commiting with connection.commit()

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to execute a stored procedure through Python with pyodbc. Right now, even with the connection.commit() the transaction does not commit and does not update my table.

Here is my code:

```
connection=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=Database;Trusted_Connection=yes')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("EXEC [dbo].[Prevision]")
connection.commit()
```

I have tried:
- Connecting to SQL Server Native Client;
- Setting autocommit=TRUE on the connection;

Nothing worked.
Can you help me?

Thank you,

Comment: Does your stored procedure have `SET NOCOUNT ON;` as its first executable statement? If not, then try adding it.

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved the problem for one of my stored procedures. I am trying to launch another that just stops working on the first select statement. I run the Stored Procedure through SQL Server and it works fine. Do you know what it might be causing this?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the stored procedure that is failing?